# Entity Framework not updating existing related entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a project which uses Entity Framework extensively. And it all works fine.

However, there is one update that I am trying to make and it does not update, nor is an error thrown.

The basic process is that I take an existing entity, work with it to create a new (and different type) of entity. The new entity saves just fine, but the existing one does not.

Typically when I have encountered this, it means that the entity is not attached to the context. However, it is, and I have tried attaching it again as well as "Adding" it, but I have had no luck.

```
        if (fileRowEntity != null)
        {
            this.Context.FileRowEntities.Attach(fileRowEntity);
            fileRowEntity.FileRowStatusId = (int)FileRowStatus.Converted;
            fileRowEntity.EdiDocument = ediDocument;
        }

        ediDocument.InsertedDate = DateTime.Now;
        ediDocument.EdiDocumentGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        ediDocument.DocumentMetatdata = null;
        this.Context.EdiDocuments.Add(ediDocument);
        var count = this.Context.SaveChanges();
```

The `ediDocument` is saved, but the `fileRowEntity` is not saved.

I am tearing my hair out trying to figure this out.  I have tried a second explicit save on the `fileRowEntity` but it comes back with zero changes saved:

```
        if (fileRowEntity != null)
        {
            fileRowEntity.EdiDocumentId = ediDocument.EdiDocumentId;
            fileRowEntity.Column100 = "X";
            this.Context.FileRowEntities.Attach(fileRowEntity);
            count = this.Context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

`count` is always zero, and the database is not updated.

I don't know what else to try to debug this.

Comment: Attaching an entity does not mark it as modified... have you tried `Context.Entry(fileRowEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;`? (no need to attach it, this will attach the entity if it's detached aswell). Unless the entity is a proxy and/or it was loaded beforehand, EF will not know there were changes to it unless you tell it to, so it won't do any updates. Marking it as `Modified` explicitly should work.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, that does indeed make the save work.  Does this mean that the entity was in fact not in the same context?  As far as I can tell, the same entity manager is used to retrieve the entities as save them.

Comment: When an entity is loaded from the database, it's original values (as they were retrieved) are stored in the context (you can actually check them in `Context.Entry(entity).OriginalValues`)... when the dbcontext checks its changes (by calling `DetectChanges`), it stores the new values (you can check them in `Context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues`), and if any of those are modified, then an `UPDATE` is generated when saving changes. So if the original entity was retrieved from the database by that same context, then yes, it should detect the changes and save the modifications

Comment: Then again, just the fact that it lets you attach the entity, proves that it was indeed not retrieved by that same context. I'm not 100% sure, but I think `Attach` throws an exception when you try to attach an already attached entity (modifying its state doesn't, so it's always safer).

Comment: I'm posting all of this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attaching an entity to a context does not mark it as modified.

In your case, the presumption is that the context instance where you are calling `SaveChanges()` on, is not the same that retrieved the `fileRowEntity` object, so it doesn't know that it was modified (or what was modified).

When a `DbContext` retrieves an object from the store, it stores a copy of its original values (unless you used `AsNoTracking()` on that query), and whenever it detects changes by a call to `DetectChanges()`, which you can make explicitly, but the normal `DbContext` implementation will call it by itself at many points), it'll store the new object values. If there are differences between those, the next call to  `SaveChanges` will update the entity in the store/database.

When you attach an entity but don't mark it as modified, it doesn't know anything has changed, so you can explicitly mark the entity as modified:

Using `Context.Entry(fileRowEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;` should tell EF that your entity was modified, and it'll generate the update command when you call `SaveChanges()` for the whole entity (it'll send all the field values in the `UPDATE` SQL). Note that doing this also attaches the entity if it was not attached to the context (no need to attach it and then set its state).

You can also mark only the properties that were modified (or change the entity `OriginalValues`), this way your query will be optimized (it'll only update the fields that have actually changed). It's a bit cumbersome to track those changes yourself, but if you need that extra optimization, it's worth a shot (personally, unless there's a critical load on the database server and every bit counts, I wouldn't do this, but your choice)

Answer (score 1):

There is a second reason for the above described behavior: This code will turn off change tracking:

```
 Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

After I found this had been set in the constructor and removed it, all worked as expected.

Comment: That's right. The default is automatic and I didn't think of the possibility that you could have disabled it. If you notice a slow behaviour after enabling automatic change detection, you can call DetectChanges explicitly. EF tends to do more detections than necessary :-)

Comment: Good point. Again, thank you, I couldn't figure this one out :)